# parameter passing from a window to another

Tags: java, javascript

i have this xhtml page represented in window1 ,

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />  
 <p:panel  id="fourP" style="width : 664px;" header="Supprimer un article">
             <br /> 
              <h:outputText value="Fournisseur :" style=" FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: small;" /> 
              <p:inputText value="#{articleinbean.artinstk.fournisseur}"  />
              <p:commandButton value=" " style="width:20px;height:30px" onclick="window.open('#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/faces/Fournisseur/Listefournisseur.xhtml','mywindow','width=400,height=200,left=0,top=100,screenX=0,screenY=100')" />            

   <p:commandButton value="Ajouter" action="#{articleinbean.ajouterarticlein()}" update=":form:messages"  />


</p:panel>

 </h:form>
```

as you can see , there is a button that opens a new window window2 , this window contains a List of `Fournisseur`

```
<h:form id="form">




       <p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{articleinbean.listefour()}" rowKey="#{car.idfourlivr}"  
                 selection="#{articleinbean.selectedfourlivr}" selectionMode="single" >  


                  <p:ajax event="rowSelect"  oncomplete="carDialog.show()"  listener="#{familleBean.onRowSelect}" />  

        <f:facet name="header">  
           Liste des articles 
        </f:facet> 
         <p:column headerText="Numero de fournisseur" >  
            #{car.idfourlivr}  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="Nom de fournisseur">  
            #{car.nomfourlivr}  
        </p:column>    
   </p:dataTable>  



     </h:form>
```

what i want to do here is showing the selected `Fournisseur` Name from the window2 in the the inputext  `<p:inputText value="#{articleinbean.artinstk.fournisseur}"  />` in the window one it means passing the `Fournisseur.getName()` from window2 to the `<p:inputText/>` in the window 1 .Thank you.

Comment: Please show the rendered HTML, preferably in a jsfiddle.net

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not seeing your HTML, if you need to defer setting the value I would suggest giving your commandbutton an ID and have this script instead on the inline script

```
window.onload=function() {
  var win;
  document.getElementById("commandButton").onclick=function
    win=window.open('#facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/faces/Fournisseur/Listefournisseur.xhtml',
  'mywindow',
  'width=400,height=200,left=0,top=100,screenX=0,screenY=100');
  }
}
```

then later you can do

```
win.document.getElementById("inputTextID").value="#{Fournisseur.getName()}";
```

or whatever it takes

Answer (score 0):

How does your bean look like? If the setter/getter for fournisseur are correctly set then by time the commandbutton is clicked it's value should have been set. And you should have been able to see that in the following window. Another thing, if you are using JSF version 2 and later you don't need those brackets () appended to the methods in your actions or values.